# NoMethodError: undefined method `valid_password?' for #<User::ActiveRecord_Relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, device

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :account
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :confirmable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable
         # :validatable


  validates_presence_of     :email
  validates                 :email, format: {with: /\A[^@]+@([^@\.]+\.)+[^@\.]+\z/ }
  # validates_uniqueness_of   :email
  validates_presence_of     :password, if: :password_required?
  validates_confirmation_of :password, if: :password_required?
  validates_length_of       :password, within: 6..30, allow_blank: true
```

мне нужно было снять **уникальность email** для User и я закомментировал модуль # :validatable
добавив из него метод

```
protected
  def password_required?
    !persisted? || !password.nil? || !password_confirmation.nil?
  end
```

для работы системы.

Но теперь перестала работать авторизация пользователей.

```
class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  before_filter :check_captcha, only: [:create]
  skip_before_filter :require_no_authentication, only: [:create,:login_token]
  prepend_before_filter :allow_params_authentication!, only: :create

  def create
    data = {result: :error}
    if user_params[:email].present? and user_params[:password].present?
      user = User.where(email: user_params[:email].strip.downcase).where.not(role: 'notify')
      if user.present? and user.valid_password?(user_params[:password])
        sign_in user
        data = {result: admin_root_url}
      end
    end
    render json: data
  end

NoMethodError: undefined method `valid_password?' for #<User::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x005620fa18ff30>
from /home/user_name/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@wifibit/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:136:in `method_missing'
```

пробовал в свмой моделе User
переопределить метод

```
def valid_password?(password)
    Devise::Encryptor.compare(self.class, encrypted_password, password)
end
```

и в private и в protected и просто, не видит и все.

Еще для снятия уникальности провел миграцию

```
class ChangeIndexUsers< ActiveRecord::Migration

  def up
    remove_index :users, :email
    add_index "users", ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: false, using: :btree
  end

  def down
    remove_index :users, :email
    add_index "users", ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true, using: :btree
  end
end
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А как собственно вы планируете аутентифицировать пользователя, если email не уникален?!! И зачем вам несколько пользователей с одинаковой почтой? Вы сломали основной принцип работы devise и теперь пытаетесь заставить его работать - это нереально, мне кажется. Будет здорово, если вы более подробно опишете задачу - по-моему, вы пытаетесь решить её не тем путём

Comment: @Василиса буду аутентифицировать буду по email и колонки role. Мне нужно разобраться и починить метод valid_password?(password).

Answer (score 0):

user = User.where(email: user_params[:email].strip.downcase).where.not(role: 'notify')

проблема была в некорректном обращении к БД через ActiveRecord а именно после запроса **.where** не был применен метод **.first** (даже если в БД нашло всего 1 запись)